# calling functions in pg_temp schema without prefix

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

In postgres the `pg_temp` schema is by default on the search path.
As explained by Tom Lane [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12887.1287636459%40sss.pgh.pa.us) functions in the `pg_temp` schema are not callable by default without a prefix for security reasons.

However he states that in order to call functions in the `pg_temp` schema without a prefix you have to explicitly add the temp schema to the search path. Unfortunately as of postgresql 9.4 this doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
set search_path to pg_temp,public;
-- create function in the temp schema
create function test_fun() returns int as $$ select 1; $$ language sql;
-- results in "function test_fun() does not exist"
select test_fun();
-- works perfectly
select pg_temp.test_fun();
```

Is there any way to call functions in the pg_temp schema without prefixing them?

This would be highly convenient for developing new functions.

Comment: Just a hint, I'm using my own schema `temp` which is emptied from time to time.

Comment: I also thought about this. This leads to another question. Is the pg_temp schema performing better than regular schemas?

Comment: Even if so, the differences wouldn't be crucial, especially during testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Tome Lane was not 100% precise on that one – I checked from 9.2 to 9.5, and in each of these you need to qualify the function with `pg_temp`. Setting `search_path` is not enough.

See PostgreSQL commit [aa27977fe21a7dfa4da4376ad66ae37cb8f0d0b5](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=aa27977fe21a7dfa4da4376ad66ae37cb8f0d0b5;hp=9350056eaa26ff404e935923fcbb75efa5c23288):

> Support explicit placement of the temporary-table schema within search_path.
>   This is needed to allow a security-definer function to set a truly secure
>   value of search_path.  Without it, a malicious user can use temporary objects
>   to execute code with the privileges of the security-definer function.  Even
>   pushing the temp schema to the back of the search path is not quite good
>   enough, because a function or operator at the back of the path might still
>   capture control from one nearer the front due to having a more exact datatype
>   match.  Hence, disable searching the temp schema altogether for functions and
>   operators.
>
> Security: CVE-2007-2138

See in particular the changes in `FuncnameGetCandidates`:

```
@@ -549,12 +586,16 @@ FuncnameGetCandidates(List *names, int nargs)
        }
        else
        {
-           /* Consider only procs that are in the search path */
+           /*
+            * Consider only procs that are in the search path and are not
+            * in the temp namespace.
+            */
            ListCell   *nsp;

            foreach(nsp, activeSearchPath)
            {
-               if (procform->pronamespace == lfirst_oid(nsp))
+               if (procform->pronamespace == lfirst_oid(nsp) &&
+                   procform->pronamespace != myTempNamespace)
                    break;
                pathpos++;
            }
```

Comment: May I ask how you checked? Did you try it out or even check the code? I'm just asking to know if there could be some option that allows to change the default behaviour.

Comment: I have amended the answer to include the pointers to the source.

Comment: By the way, I submitted a patch that fixes a documentation error that I noticed while looking at that: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B5386C6E1@ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at

Comment: What a great and detailed answer! Thanks for the effort!